# Orbeon forms and glassfish - Error: Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.xbl.BindingCache

Tags: java, glassfish, orbeon

I am trying to run Orbeon forms version 3.9 CE = community edition on glassfish. When I start the server the below exception is presented:

```
Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.xbl.BindingCache$
```

Any idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the first time the error occurs it gives: "unable to read cache manager configuration from  ...." pointing to the ehcache.xml ... and unfortunately upgrading for now is not an option...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That exception doesn't ring a bell, but 3.9 is now really old (released in 2011), so I'd recommend you try with a more recent version ([4.9](http://www.orbeon.com/download) at the time of this writing). If you still have that problem with the latest release feel free to post another question about it, and it will be easier to investigate and resolve.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the first time the error occurs it gives: "unable to read cache manager configuration from  ...." pointing to the ehcache.xml ... and unfortunately upgrading for now is not an option...any ideias?

Comment: @frohiky I understand. We don't have the bandwidth to support issues reported by the community happening with old versions of the product. So, if upgrading isn't an option, it might make sense for your organization to get a support plan with Orbeon; feel free to email info@orbeon.com to enquire about options.

Comment: of course. i understand. meanwhile what we did was to install a fresh new glassfish on a different machine and the new deploy worked just fine...it's something specific of that server...a error in the ehcache files? I don't know

Comment: @frohiky Excellent, I am glad that solved the problem, and you don't need to upgrade or worry about support just for this. And thank you for the update!